# (Python) How to calculate the average over a time period?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by

I have a dataFrame and I am trying to add a new column that calculates the average amount spent with a card over the last 3 days.

I have tried using `df[avg_card_7days] = df.groupby('card')['amount'].resample('3D', on = 'date').mean()`

The dataFrame currently looks like:

```
card          date          amount
1             2/1/10        50
2             2/1/10        40
3             2/1/10        10
1             2/2/10        20
2             2/2/10        30
3             2/2/10        30
1             2/3/10        10
2             2/3/10        30
3             2/3/10        20
...
```

But I a looking for this result:

```
card          date          amount     avg_card_3days
1             2/1/10        50         NaN
2             2/1/10        40         NaN
3             2/1/10        10         NaN
1             2/2/10        20         NaN 
2             2/2/10        30         NaN 
3             2/2/10        30         NaN 
1             2/3/10        10         26.26
2             2/3/10        30         33.33
3             2/3/10        20         20.00
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%m/%d/%y')
df = df.set_index('date')
df['avg_card_3days'] = df.groupby('card').expanding(3).amount.agg('mean').droplevel(0).sort_index()
df = df.reset_index()
df
```

**Output**

```
    date    card    amount  avg_card_3days
0   2010-02-01  1   50      NaN
1   2010-02-01  2   40      NaN
2   2010-02-01  3   10      NaN
3   2010-02-02  1   20      NaN
4   2010-02-02  2   30      NaN
5   2010-02-02  3   30      NaN
6   2010-02-03  1   10      26.666667
7   2010-02-03  2   30      33.333333
8   2010-02-03  3   20      20.000000
```

**Explanation**
Converting `date` column to `datetime` type and setting it as index.
Grouping the `df` by `card` and finding `rolling mean of 3 days` and assigning it to new column.
resetting the index to get required output.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I appreciate it.

Comment: nw, all the best!